# How can I remove the MongoDB message of Java console?

Tags: java, mongodb, netbeans, console, jongo

I have `MongoDB 3.2.9` and I am developing an Java application with `Jongo 1.3.0` but the `NetBeans` console is showing the next **red** message:

```
nov 24, 2016 2:30:17 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFORMACIÓN: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
nov 24, 2016 2:30:18 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFORMACIÓN: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:86}] to localhost:27017
nov 24, 2016 2:30:18 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFORMACIÓN: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 2, 9]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=4, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=4886848}
nov 24, 2016 2:30:19 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFORMACIÓN: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:87}] to localhost:27017
```

As this project is a University homework, my teacher will say me this is a problem; for this reason I would like remove theses messages or change its color.

As additional information I am using:

- bson4jackson-2.7.0.jar
- jackson-annotations-2.7.3.jar
- jackson-core-2.7.3.jar
- jackson-databind-2.7.3.jar
- mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar

... and when I change `mongo-java-driver`version, my application not working.

This is my java code:

```
collection = (new Jongo(new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 ).getDB("mydb"))).getCollection("mycollection");
```

Comment: It seems these messages are just INFO, so maybe it's a netbeans config issue...

Comment: MordechayS Yes, I know. My teacher is....stubborn

Comment: Thank you! Mohasen89z. I explain my solution as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all.
This was my solution:

```
Logger mongoLogger = Logger.getLogger( "org.mongodb.driver" );
mongoLogger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
```